# Jest tests failing randomly

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I have a jest config like:

```
module.exports = {
    "projects": [
        {
            name: "project1",
            displayName: "Project 1",
            bail: false,
            clearMocks: false,
            collectCoverage: false,
            .................
        },
        {
            name: "project2",
            displayName: "Project 2",
            preset: 'ts-jest',
            testEnvironment: 'node',
            globals: {
                'ts-jest': {
                    tsConfig: 'sub_directory/tsconfig.jest.json'
                }
            },
            testMatch: ["<rootDir>/sub_directory/**/?(*.)spec.ts"],
            transform: { '^.+\\.ts?$':'ts-jest' },
            moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'js'],
            collectCoverageFrom: [
                'lib/**/*.ts',
                'public/**/*.ts',
                'index.ts'
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

sub_directory/tsconfig.jest.json :

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "../types/ts/static",
      "../node_modules/@types",
      "../node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build"
    ],
    "types": [
      "node", "lodash", "gen", "jest", "jest-jasmine2"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.js",
    "**/*.test.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules", "build", "coverage"
  ]
}
```

Now when I run the jest tests in parallel (as they would by default),
I get failures in just project 2 test files. The failure is always the same, but the files in which it occurs are random.

```
Summary of all failing tests
 FAIL  sub_directory/some_path1/a.spec.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module './testPathPatternToRegExp' from 'index.js'

      at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:259:17)

 FAIL  sub_directory/some_path2/b.spec.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module './testPathPatternToRegExp' from 'index.js'

      at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:259:17)

 FAIL  sub_directory/some_path3/c.spec.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module './testPathPatternToRegExp' from 'index.js'

      at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:259:17)
```

the relevant package versions are:

```
 "@types/jest": "24.0.18",
....
 "jest": "24.8.0",
 "jest-junit": "5.1.0",
....
 "ts-jest": "24.1.0",
```

The tests in `project1` never fail.
Also when
- only tests of `project2` are run
OR
- `project1` and `project2` are run one after the other(in any order)
everything works fine.

Why would this be happening?

Comment: Are the modules that are throwing errors in the broken tests also mocked in completely different tests?

Comment: @JoelAK the module throwing the error is `jest-resolve`. It is not mocked anywhere as it is not called in any functionality